# Changing map marker icon on zoom change

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use this code to change the marker icons when the user zooms out to a zoom level lower than 13:

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        float zoomLevel = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        if (previousZoom <= 13 && zoomLevel > 13){
            for(int i=0; i<markers_location.length; i++){
                markers.get(i).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("marker_100",47,75)));
            }
        } else if (previousZoom > 13 && zoomLevel <= 13){
            for(int i=0; i<markers_location.length; i++){
                markers.get(i).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("dot",25,25)));
            }
        }
        previousZoom = zoomLevel;
    }
});
```

This works fine, but it takes about half a second for the icons to change after the camera stops moving. I guess it is because the OnCameraIdleListener is only called when all other animations are finished.So I tried this with OnCameraMoveListener (because this is called once every frame), but that froze for a moment when it reached the zoom level 13 to change all the icons. Is there a better or faster way to do this?